# Magento create products in bulk from csv programatically

Tags: php, csv, magento-1.7, product

I am new to Magento and facing problem with some basic functionalities. I am currently using this to [Create product through API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.create.html)

but I am searching for some technique using which I can upload all the products in a .csv file in bulk. So that the API gets called once to insert a list of products.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to you to use MAGMI Please check this link  http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/ for information.

MAGMI provide a product importer for magento that can handle several thousands of products at a reasonable pace compared to magento dataflow.

Thank

Comment: Thx. But, I want the bulk upload through coding and not through only UI.